# Angular, a filter for discounts - passing variables into filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a little app where a user can play around with  discounts to see an price of a product. They pick a product which comes from a drop down - an ng-repeat, then they select 1 of 3 discounts, and I would like to try and display the result with the discount price. So My first thought is maybe a filter can do this? But I'm unclear if this is the correct direction with this.

Here's what I have

In the controller -

```
$scope.myItems  = [{"id":0,"name":"item1", "price" : 3.50 },{"id":1,"name":"item2", "price" : 5.50 },{"id":2,"name":"item 3", "price" : 4.75 }];
$scope.discount1 = 0.7;
$scope.discount2 = 0.25;
//the users information that tells us which discounts he/she has
$scope.user = {'name' : 'Ted', 'discount1' : false, 'discount2': true};
```

So the discounts would just be a multiplier if they are selected to give the discounted price.

And on the view I have :

```
<select ng-model="itemSelected" ng-options="item as item.name for item in myItems"> </select>
```

and I would want to do something like:

```
<p>Your price:</p>
{{itemSelected.price | (filtered by discounts if true in $scope.user) }}
```

Is something like this possible? If so I could really use some guidance on how to take this problem down. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.filter('discount', function(){
  return function(input, discount){
    if (input) return  input*(1-discount);
  }
})
```

In your html

```
{{itemSelected.price | discount : discount1}}
```

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZjPhdMIbfm3pqBthXdiq?p=preview)

**EDIT**

if you want to determine the discount using your object (which in my opinion is a bad structure, but maybe you it's for demo purposes) then you can have this piece of code in the controller

```
$scope.discount = ($scope.user.discount1 && $scope.discount1)||($scope.user.discount2 && $scope.discount2)
```

and use in html

```
{{itemSelected.price | discount : discount}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that you really need filter for this, is fairly easy to this calc without one:

```
<p ng-if="itemSelected && user">Your #1 price: 
  {{itemSelected.price * (user.discount1 ? 1- discount1 : 1) | number : 2}}</p>
```

Comment: Could something like this work if I had more discounts? like 3-4 maybe. Thanks!

Comment: Not really sure  how that works, 4 discounts for the same items?. Doesn't really make sense to me. Even with a filter you have to make html adjustments anyway , so this seems to me just as simple

Comment: Not stacking, just 4 different ones to pick from, only 1 active though.

Comment: `$scope.userDiscount` makes it pretty easy. Will need to do something like that for filter also